# Looping over List of different generic types in c#

Tags: c#, generics, arraylist

I have a list comprised of different generic types like such:

```
public abstract class BaseClass {}

public class BaseChild<T> : BaseClass {
   public SomeOtherClass<T> data;
}

List<BaseClass> items;
items.Add(new BaseChild<int>());
items.Add(new BaseChild<bool>());
items.Add(new BaseChild<double>());
```

I now want to loop over this list and pass the `data` property of each item of type `SomeOtherClass` to a field of the same type in another generic class. Something like this

```
public class GenClass<T> {
   public SomeOtherClass<T> assignHere;
}

for(int i=0;i<=items.Count;i++){
   // this does not work. It is unable to get data since it is not
   // defined in BaseClass and the List is of type BaseClass
   items[i].data;
   // somehow assign to assignHere field in GenClass<T> since I don't know type
}
```

I have two questions:

1. How do I access the data field, since it is only defined on the inheritors but not the parent class? The List I loop over is of Type `BaseClass` and not `BaseChild<T>`
2. How do I assign the data to the `assignHere` field in the `GenClass<T>` if I don't know it's Type while looping?

Edit:
Code for `SomeOtherClass<T>`

```
public class SomeOtherClass<T>{
   public T Value;
   public GameEvent<T> event
}

public GameEvent<T>:UnityEvent<T>{
   public void Raise(T value){
      //does something
   }

}
```

Edit #2: Here is one implementation that I have tried and works. Is this better?

```
public abstract class BaseButton
    {
        public string displayText;

        public abstract void TriggerButton();
    }

public class IntButton : BaseButton
{
    public IntEvent triggerEvent;
    public int Value;

    public override void TriggerButton()
    {
        triggerEvent.Raise(Value);
    }
}

public class IntEvent : BaseGameEvent<int>{}

public abstract class BaseGameEvent<T>{
    public void Raise(T value){
        // do something
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the advantage of a list of the base type if you're needing to work with child type? Is it guaranteed there are only children in the list?

Comment: Can you add the code of the class SomeOtherClass?

Comment: Take a look over [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching)

Comment: Why would you want to store different instances of different types - and yes, `BaseChild<int>` and `BaseChild<double>` are completely unrelated types -  into a single list? Does not make much sense, IMHO.

Comment: Generics are a **compile-time-feature**. When you put the actual types at **runtime**, how should the compiler ever infer the right types? This is the compiler has no chance to know, that item at index 2 for instance is of type `BaseChild<double>`. So even if you had access to `data` in any way, there´s not much you could do with it.

Comment: @HimBromBeere i have added some pseudo-ish code to clarify. Basically I want to loop through the list and dynamically populate some buttons. I want these buttons to be able to emit events but with different types. Thus I want one list which can store all the data for these buttons. I loop over, populate the buttons and when clicked, each button emits its own event with the correct type value. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Orwel just added some code of SomeOtherClass which itself contains an eventclasstype with a method that requires a type T param

Comment: @shekit Makes sense, but simply isn´t possible during compile-time, as the compiler has no knowledge of the **actual** types. Imagine that **was** possible. How would you know which type the `value` passed to the event should have? So how would you raise the event?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils yes only children in the list but of different types

Comment: @HimBromBeere thanks for clarifying. Thats a shame, any ideas on how else I could approach this?

Comment: Why do you even have a single list in the first place, instead of 3?

Comment: @HimBromBeere in my app, each page(there will be several) can have different quantity and types of buttons, it won't always be these three. There could be more/less types. For each page, I'm creating a List<BaseClass> that stores all the button data. That way I can use the same code to loop through and populate the buttons.

Comment: @shekit really seems like you are overcomplicating this problem and abusing both generics and polymorphism - you might want to take a step back and ask about the actual problem instead of the specific mechanism you are trying to solve it.

Comment: where does the data come from? could you clarify the data flow? usually you would try to make a method without input parameters but fire the event from within

Comment: @MongZhu yes I tried what I think you are suggesting in another implementation. I added it in the question as Edit #2. Is that what you are suggesting? It works but was wondering if it's a better/worse approach

Comment: @AntP I've added another implementation I have tried which seems to be working. Is that a better mechanism?

Answer (score -1):

With reflection :

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

        List<BaseClass> items = new List<BaseClass>();
        items.Add(new BaseChild<int>());
        items.Add(new BaseChild<bool>());
        items.Add(new BaseChild<double>());

        for (int i = 0; i <= items.Count; i++)
        {
            var generated = Convert(items[i]);
            if (generated is GenClass<int> genInt)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(genInt?.assignHere?.Value);
            }
            else if (generated is GenClass<bool> genBool)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(genBool?.assignHere?.Value);
            }
        }
    }

    static object Convert(BaseClass item)
    {
        var type = item.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0];
        var method = typeof(Program).GetMethod("GenericConvert", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic).MakeGenericMethod(type);
        return method.Invoke(null, new[] { item });
    }

    static GenClass<T> GenericConvert<T>(BaseChild<T> from)
    {
        return new GenClass<T> { assignHere = from.data };
    }
}
```